# NameError: name 'tk' is not defined repl.it

Tags: python, tkinter, themes

hey beginner programmer here, making a to do list for a high school assignment and cant figure out this error. its also my first time using python as I usually use java and JavaScript for projects. Im trying to add a dark and light mode to my program. Am I doing this correctly? btw, i'm using the online ide repl.it

here's my code for reference

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
import tkinter.ttk as ttk 
import pickle

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("To-Do List")

def add_task():
    task = entry_task.get()
    if task != "":
        listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
        entry_task.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning", message="Please enter a task")

def delete_task():
     try:
         task_index = listbox_tasks.curselection()[0]
         listbox_tasks.delete(task_index)
     except:
         tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning", message="Please select a task first")

 def load_tasks():
     try:
         tasks = pickle.load(open("tasks.dat", "rb"))
         listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
         for task in tasks:
             listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
     except:
         tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning", message="Cant find saved task file")

 def save_tasks():
     tasks = listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size())
     pickle.dump(tasks, open("tasks.dat", "wb"))

 # Dark and light modes   
 app = tk.Tk()
 app.geometry("200x400")
 app.title("Changing Themes")
 # Setting Theme
 style = ThemedStyle(app)
 style.set_theme("scidgrey")

 # Button Widgets
 Def_Btn = tk.Button(app,text='Default Button')
 Def_Btn.pack()
 Themed_Btn = ttk.Button(app,text='Themed button')
 Themed_Btn.pack()

 # Scrollbar Widgets
 Def_Scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(app)
 Def_Scrollbar.pack(side='right',fill='y')
 Themed_Scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(app,orient='horizontal')
 Themed_Scrollbar.pack(side='top',fill='x')

 # Entry Widgets
 Def_Entry = tk.Entry(app)
 Def_Entry.pack()
 Themed_Entry = ttk.Entry(app)
 Themed_Entry.pack()

 # Create GUI
 frame_tasks = tkinter.Frame(root)
 frame_tasks.pack()

 listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(frame_tasks, height=10, width=50)
 listbox_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

 scrollbar_tasks = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame_tasks)
 scrollbar_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)

 listbox_tasks.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tasks.set)
 scrollbar_tasks.config(command=listbox_tasks.yview)

 entry_task = tkinter.Entry(root, width=50)
 entry_task.pack()

 button_add_task = tkinter.Button(root, text="Add a task", width=48, command=add_task)
 button_add_task.pack()

 button_delete_task = tkinter.Button(root, text="Delete a task", width=48, command=delete_task)
 button_delete_task.pack()

 button_load_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text="Load a task list", width=48, command=load_tasks)
 button_load_tasks.pack()

 button_save_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text="Save your task list", width=48, command=save_tasks)
 button_save_tasks.pack()

 root = tkinter()
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you link to the repl?

Comment: sure. https://repl.it/@DuckieBoi/to-do-list?scrlybrkr=4db69e9a#main.py

Answer (score 5):

repl.it has nothing to do with the issue. You have lines referencing "`tk`", like `app = tk.Tk()`, but you never defined anything called `tk`. It looks like some of your code expects you to have imported Tkinter via `import tkinter as tk`, in which case `tk` would be valid. But you also have code expecting it to be called `tkinter`, like `root = tkinter.Tk()`. It seems like your code was inspired from multiple sources, some of which had Tkinter imported as `tk`, and some where it was imported as `tkinter`. All you have to do is replace all `tk`s with `tkinter`. For example, this line:

```
Def_Btn = tk.Button(app,text='Default Button')
```

would become:

```
Def_Btn = tkinter.Button(app,text='Default Button')
```

Comment: oh ok I see. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably coming from your import

I observed that you did not import Tkinter as tk but you keep on using the tk. try importing it

Answer (score 0):

Since you have:

```
import tkinter
```

Python looks for tkinter not tk since you have not told python that you want to use the module with the alias 'tk'

Your solution is:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

You probably forgot that you were using `tkinter` instead of `tk`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from your import statement, you imported tkinter as ttk but you kept on using tk